# Password Protect Form Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have the following code on my form on the on_open

```
Dim PassWord As String
PassWord = InputBox("Enter Password")

    If PassWord = "1234" Then
        'Open Form
        Exit Sub
    Else
        MsgBox ("You're not authorized.")
        DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
    End If
```

The problem I have is, if the user doesn't enable content the password box doesn't kick in.

Is there an alternative solution so it will always ask for a password whether the enable content is clicked or not?

Answer (score 2):

The content the user has to enable is the executing of macros and code, so this way of protecting your database will only ever work when all users have done that.

And even if they have enabled it, they can easily circumvent it by shift-doubleclicking your database to open it without executing any code at all.

There are a couple of ways to protect your database with a password:

- Choose File -> Info -> Encrypt database. This will allow you to use a single password to encrypt your entire database. It'll do pretty much the same thing as you have now in your code, only safer.
- File -> Save As -> Make ACCDE. This will turn your database into an executable-only file. **This also means you can no longer make any changes to your database structure!** You should split front-end and back-end and keep a development copy of your front-end which you can push out to your users whenever you made any changes.

Answer (score 0):

Create a macro with name **AutoExec**

When a database starts, Access runs the AutoExec macro before it runs any other macros or VBA code.

AutoExec macro has following Condition & Action
[image]

This will run before the macro is enabled.

[image]

Not recommended way as it can be easily bypassed by users.

Comment: @Philly500 Did it help?